# Check if string is equal to one of many given strings

Tags: php, string

I want to check whether string is one of the given strings. It would look something like this.

```
$string 'test';


// if given string is 'test' function will return false.
function checkIfIsSubstring($string)
{
if (strcmp($string, 'test2') )
   return true;
if (strcmp($string, 'test3') )
   return true;
if (strcmp($string, 'test4') )
   return true;
return false;
}
```

is there php function what would do same thing, without me creating a new function?

Comment: Yes, `in_array`. The first example in the doc page is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are the strings you are checking against always the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values into an array and then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
$array = array('test1', 'test2', 'test3');
$string = 'test1';    

if(in_array($string, $array)) {
    // do something
}
```